# Is there a way to multithread a SqlDataReader?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, multithreading, c#-3.0

I have a Sql Query which returns me over half million rows to process... The process doesn't take really long, but I would like to speed it up a little bit with some multiprocessing. Considering the code below, is it possible to multithread something like that easily?

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // ...process row
    }
}
```

It would be perfect if I could simply get a cursor at the beginning and in the middle of the list of results. That way, I could have two thread processing the records. However the SqlDataReader doesn't allow me to do that...

Any idea how I could achieve that?

Comment: If you know how to partition your query you can run 2 queries in parallel.

Comment: Hi, did you end up at a solution for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set up a producer/consumer queue, with one producer process to pull from the reader and queue records as fast as it can, but do no "processing".  Then some other number of processes (how many you want depends on your system) to dequeue and process each queued record.

Comment: Hmm.. odd, but I couldn't find a generic producer/consumer pattern already implemented.  Playing with my own now, but input here is appreciated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916863/generic-net-produce-consumer

Comment: Did you end up coding your own producer/consumer, if so, are you able to share it?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't read that many rows on the client.

That being said, you can partition your query into multiple queries and execute them in parallel. That means launch multiple SqlCommands in separate threads and have them each churn a partition of the result. The A+ question is how to partition the result, and this depends largely o your data and your query:

1. You can use a range of keys (eg. `ID betweem 1 and 10000`, `ID between 10001 and 20000` etc)
2. You can use an attribute (eg. `RecordTypeID IN (1,2)`, `RecordTypeID IN (3,4)` etc)
3. You can use a synthetic range (ie. `ROW_NUMBER() BETWEEN 1 and 1000` etC), but this is very problematic to pull of right
4. You can use a hash (eg. `BINARY_CHECKSUM(*)%10 == 0`, `BINARY_CHECKSUM(*)%10==1` etc)

You just have to be very careful that the partition queries do no overlap and **block** during execution (ie. scan the same records and acquire X locks), thus serializing each other.

Comment: I don't think this is a very good idea - The developer should not have to know this much about the data (or what it could look like in the future). Plus, any solution should be reusable in other scenarios. A genuine multithreaded solution would best, like producer/consumer mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

Is it a simple ranged query like WHERE Id between 1 and 500000? If so you can just kick off N queries that each return 1/N of the range. But it helps to know where you are bottlenecked with the single threaded approach. If you are doing contiguous reads from one disk spindle to fulfill the query then you should probably stick with a single thread. If it is partitioned across spindles by some range then you can intelligently tune your queries to maximize throughput from disk (i.e. read from each disk in parallel with separate queries). If you expect all of the rows to be in memory then you can parallelize at will. But if the query is more complex then you may not be able to easily partition it without incurring a bunch of overhead. Most of the time the above options will not apply well and the producer/consumer that Joel mentioned will be the only place to parallelize. Depending on how much time you spend processing each row, this may be provide only trivial gains.