# Generic .Net Producer/Consumer

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, producer-consumer

I'm toying with the idea of implementing a generic Producer/Consumer pair + processing queue in C# for fun.  The idea is you can just create objects that implement appropriate IProducer and IConsumer interfaces (default implementations supplied), which will consist mainly of delegates, pass them to a `QueueProcessor` class instance, tell it how many consumers you want, and go.

But I say to myself, "Self, surely this has been done before."

So does anyone know of a **good**, *generic* implementation of the producer/consumer pattern in C# (VB.Net is okay, too)?  The basic requirements I'm looking for:

- Use generics for the produced and consumed types (input, queued task, and output types, or any combination thereof)
- Allow you specify how many consumers will work the queue
- Allow you to link up or chain multiple queues into a pipeline (tricky with multiple Consumers, I know)
- Allow you to implement your own Producers and Consumers
- Allow you to turn any IEnumerable into a producer (okay if I have to implement that myself, as long it's possible)
- Delegate based (you can use lambda syntax for the basic consumer or producer work to process a single item)

Or if there is none, what pitfalls have prevented it and do you have any thoughts on how to implement it?

Comment: Have you looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx ?

Comment: Yes, and IProducerConsumerCollection<T>, but none of that existed yet when I first asked the question. Write up a post about the support in 4.0 and you'll get an easy upvote from me.

Comment: Argh! I don't know how this keeps happening... I'm always ending up on 2-year old posts :P

Comment: Hi Joel Coehoorn, please take a look at this [Producer-Consumer example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733793/implementing-the-producer-consumer-pattern-in-c-sharp/47179576#47179576) which uses BlockingCollection<T>. It may be useful for building your Producer-Consumer classes in case you go for building your own Producer-Consumer framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Microsoft CCR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb648752.aspx) contains much of what you need.

[Here](http://www.lnbogen.com/2008/02/04/microsoft-ccr-clean-way-to-write-parallel-code-in-net/) are some code samples and usage notes.

Comment: It is not a perfect framework though, lacking some obvious stuff like the ability to STOP the processing and WAIT for remaining tasks.

We are enhancing the framework in our dev team, if you need more help let me know...

Answer (score 2):

Marc Gravell wrote a nice example blocking queue in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530211/creating-a-blocking-queuet-in-net/530228#530228).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) ?

Comment: I don't see anything in there that does what I'm asking for.

Comment: Not to say I didn't see some things in there that would be very useful in implementing this, though.

Comment: So you'll be putting any enhancments you do inyour impl up there in time then... :P